# Android UI very slow because of invalidateOptionsMenu()

Tags: android

I am using `invalidateOptionsMenu()` to update the action bar but it slows down my app like hell. The `invalidateOptionsMenu()` makes an infinite loop. Here is my code -

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if((lockScreenSetting(getContentResolver()) == 1)){
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.filex, menu);
            return true;
        } else{
            return false;
        }
    }


    public int lockScreenSetting (ContentResolver contentResolver)
    {
        boolean isLockEnabled = true;
        KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        isLockEnabled = km.isKeyguardSecure();
        long mode = android.provider.Settings.Secure.getLong(contentResolver, PASSWORD_TYPE_KEY,
                DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_SOMETHING);
       // if (mode == DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_SOMETHING)

            if (android.provider.Settings.Secure.getInt(contentResolver, Settings.Secure.LOCK_PATTERN_ENABLED, 0) == 1){
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                return Constants.UNLOCK_WITH_PATTERN;
            }
            else if(isLockEnabled){
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                return Constants.UNLOCK_WITH_PIN;
            }
            else{
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            return Constants.UNLOCK_WITH_NONE_OR_SLIDER;
            }
}
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onCreateOptionsMenu` is triggered `invalidateOptionsMenu()`, so you are calling `lockScreenSetting` infinitely, so use a field instead.

```
int lockSetting = -1;    

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if(lockSetting == 1){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.filex, menu);
        return true;
    } else{
        lockScreenSetting(getContentResolver());
        return false;
    }
}


public void lockScreenSetting (ContentResolver contentResolver)
{
    boolean isLockEnabled = true;
    KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    isLockEnabled = km.isKeyguardSecure();
    long mode = android.provider.Settings.Secure.getLong(contentResolver, PASSWORD_TYPE_KEY,
            DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_SOMETHING);
   // if (mode == DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_SOMETHING)

        if (android.provider.Settings.Secure.getInt(contentResolver, Settings.Secure.LOCK_PATTERN_ENABLED, 0) == 1){
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            lockSetting = Constants.UNLOCK_WITH_PATTERN;
        }
        else if(isLockEnabled){
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            lockSetting = Constants.UNLOCK_WITH_PIN;
        }
        else{
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            lockSetting = Constants.UNLOCK_WITH_NONE_OR_SLIDER;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Needed little bit modification. Needed to call lockScreenSetting from onResume() and not from onCreateOptionsMenu()

Answer (score 0):

A call to `invalidateOptionsMenu()` will cause `onCreateOptionsMenu` to be called thus causing your`lockScreenSetting` method to be called.

Comment: But it is called infinitely causing UI to slow down. What can be done

Comment: Remove the call to lockScreenSetting from onCreateOptionsMenu